# azure runbook get who executed the job

Tags: azure, automation, azure-powershell, azure-runbook

I was working with azure runbooks in automation accounts for quite a while but recently I was tasked to identify who was executing the runbook.

I noticed that there is a fied called "Executed by" when you get information from a job, but seems that field is being removed by MSFT.

Checking the logs I can see the calls to the runbook but the job id stated in the log doesn't match the one in the jobid in the runbook inside the automation account.

I was wondering how can I match an execution on a runbook with a entry in the log.

any idea with powershell or by calling the REST API directly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the user who started the Automation job using the `startedBy` field returned in the [Get-AzureRmAutomationJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.automation/v2.3.0/get-azurermautomationjob) and [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163826.aspx).

This will require passing in the job id, which you can get using:
`$PsPrivateMetadata.JobId.Guid`

Comment: Thanks for your response but already tried that and the field "StartedBy" is empty. That's why I was checking the Azure logs to try to find the loggued execution. If I go to the portal under activity log I can see the executor of the job but if I try to get that by powershell or API there is no possible way to match an execution with an entry in the logs.